# Couchdb: Get all documents from all databases with curl

Tags: database, curl, get, couchdb

I need to save the content of all documents from all databases in a file. I know that I can get all documents from one database with curl:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/dbname/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

and I try this for all db:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/_all_dbs/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: In what environment are you running curl?
I don't think it's possible to get all documents in one request, as it would compromise the data, but you could write a script for it.

Comment: I run it from the terminal (os x).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A script like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/_all_dbs | sed 's/\[//' | sed 's/\]//' | sed 's/\"//g')

IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "$string"

for database in "${array[@]}"
do
    $(curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/$database/_all_docs?include_docs=true >> allData.txt)
done
```

This will send one request for all documents to each database and append the result to allData.txt, you probebly need to fix the data somehow to a format you like, but you will have it all there.

The sed:s remove `[`, `]` and `"` from first GET request.

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a way to keep the database name in the doc ?

Comment: You could add a line in the for loop, something like:
`echo database >> allData.txt`
this will add the database name to your file.